# Selection Change affecting cells outside of range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Col As Long = 2

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = "T"
        Target.Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M7:M98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = "I"
        Target.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
        Target.Offset(, -1).ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N7:N98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = "D"
        Range(Target.Offset(, -1), Target.Offset(, -2)).ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This code is causing a slight problem for me. Any time I select an entire row within the ranges, every cell within the range gets changed to "T". Given the consistency of the code, if I delete the string with "T", then the entire row would be filled with "I"

What can be adjusted to trigger **only** if cells within the range are selected?

Comment: `If Target.Count >1 then Exit Sub`

Comment: Also, `Range(Target.Offset(, -1), Target.Offset(, -2)).ClearContents` can be `Target.Offset(, -2).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Col As Long = 2

    If Target.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

Added this to the top of the code, it will now exit the Sub if more than one cell is selected even if one of the selected cells are within the appropriate range.

Comment: Cleaned out the excess code, hopefully this asnwers a bit better what the change was.

Answer (score 1):

After checking to see if the Selection intersects with the various ranges, only deal with the part of Target that intersects with the various ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Col As Long = 2

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98"))
            .Value = "T"
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
        End With
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M7:M98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Intersect(Target, Range("M7:M98"))
            .Value = "I"
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
        End With
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N7:N98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Intersect(Target, Range("N7:N98"))
            .Value = "D"
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
        End With
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Optional Alternative:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Col As Long = 2

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98"))
            .Value = "T"
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
        End With
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("M7:M98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Intersect(Target, Range("M7:M98"))
            .Value = "I"
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
        End With
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("N7:N98")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Intersect(Target, Range("N7:N98"))
            .Value = "D"
            .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
        End With
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I like how it assigns the appropriate value even if I select two cells in separate ranges. However, for some reason the cells are not clearing the contents properly when I tried using it.

Comment: I thought about that; You may want to reverse the sequence with N7:N98 first and L7:L98 last. In other words, the cells are clearting but they are being filled in after they are cleared. You could also change the latter two conditions to ElseIf so only one would be processed instead of all three.

Comment: I tried swapping the order and it doesn't seem to work either. How would you implement an Else If?

Comment: See above. You really should have been able to research/figure out this on your own.

Comment: Fair enough, I shant bother you further. I did digure out why the cells were not clearing properly. As the code stands, it is deleting 2 cells to the right of the selection. The objective was to clear the other results. The last two "ClearContents" strings needed to be adjusted accordingly.